# Validate Customer Name array with regex conditions in java

Tags: java, arrays, regex

I have an requirement to validate the customer name, with few conditions in java (**validate only with regular expression**). The customer name will be in string array and passed to a method. The validateCustomer(String[] names) should validate the customer name and return only the valid customer names in array. The criteria for validating the customer names are as below.

1. The name can contain only alphabets and spaces.
2. Each word should be separated by a space and the name should not start or end with a space.
3. The first character of each word of the name should be an upper case alphabet.
4. Special characters should not be allowed.
5. The length of the name should be between 2 and 75 characters.

> Since the conditons can be updated later i need only regex validation
> and not using any other methods like String.length().

I tried with few regex, but failing with some conditions.
A Sample tried

```
[((([A-Z][a-zA-Z])([+\\s]?[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*))]{2,75}
```

Comment: *"contain only alphabets"* You mean "contain only letters". An alphabet is something different, e.g. the Spanish alphabet includes letters like `ñ`, which is not in the English alphabet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z\\h]{2,75}$)[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*(?:\\h+[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=[a-zA-Z\\h]{2,75}$)` Assert 2-75 chars a-zA-Z or a horizontal space
- `[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*` Match an uppercase char A-Z and optional chars a-zA-Z
- `(?:\\h+[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)*` Repeat the previous preceded by 1+ horizontal spaces
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mkPq6k/1)

If you want a single space:

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z ]{2,75}$)[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*(?: [A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fKWEZU/1)

Comment: First time I see `\h`, how does it compare to `\s` or even ` ` (simple space)?

Comment: @sp00m `\h` matches horizontal whitespace chars, `\s` also matches newlines.

Comment: Oh OK, interesting, so a bit more than a simple space [apparently](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html#more): tabs + all from https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Zs (just sharing it here so that OP is aware).

Comment: A tab is not a space, so use of `\h` is wrong. Just use an actual space character.

Comment: @Andreas The OP uses `\s` which is even broader.

Comment: Yes, and I pointed that out in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68006396/5221149), as well as all the other errors in the attempt by OP. Given all the other errors in that attempt, I don't consider the use of `\s` to be defining. I consider requirement *"Each word should be separated by **a space**"* to be defining, i.e. space-only and only exactly one of them (also wrong in OPs attempt and in this answer).

Comment: @Andreas That is great! I read the pattern in the question and see chars A-Z a-z, 
 whitespace chars and a notion about alphabets. Let's wait for some feedback from the OP.

Comment: @The Fourth Bird Yes, There should be only one space between the words. Tabs are not allowed in customer's name.
"Fourth  Bird" valid? =false (it contains double space), "Fouth Bird" valid? =false (it contains tab).

I replaced \\h as \\u0020 and suits current requirement.
 ^(?=[a-zA-Z\\u0020]{2,75}$)[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*(?:\\u0020[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)*$

**Thank you both (Andreas & The fourth bird), for sharing your knowledge.**

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is wrong:

```
┌─ Definitely wrong!! Remove this
│               ┌─ Missing '*' to allow 1 to many words
│               │   ┌ '+' should not be allowed
│               │   │  ┌ Only space allowed, not other whitespace characters
│               │   │  │ ┌ Space is required between words, so remove '?'
│               │   │  │ │              ┌ Missing '*' to allow 1 to many words
│               │   │  │ │              │ ┌ Definitely wrong!! Remove this
│               │   │  │ │              │ │
[((([A-Z][a-zA-Z])([+\\s]?[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*))]{2,75}
```

What you want:

```
┌─ Must be 2-75 characters long (positive lookahead)
│          ┌─ Word must be uppercase letter
│          │    ┌─ followed by 0 or more letters
│          │    │        ┌─ followed by 0 or more words separated by single space
(?=.{2,75})[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*(?: [A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)*
```

The above regex must be used with `matches()`. If to be used with `find()`, it needs `^` and `$` anchors.

The above regex only allows A-Z letters. For support of international letters like `ñ`, use this instead:

```
(?=.{2,75})\p{Lu}\p{L}*(?: \p{Lu}\p{L}*)*
```

Remember to double the `\` when used in a Java string literal.